# Show different message on Password validation in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have passowrd rule like this

```
passwordRule(value){
 const pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/;
          return (
            pattern.test(value) ||
            "Min. 8 characters with at least one capital letter, a number and a special character."
          );
}
```

which I am using currently in

```
 <v-text-field
            autocomplete="current-password"
            :value="userPassword"
            label="Enter password"
            :append-icon="value ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            :type="value ? 'password' : 'text'"
            :rules="[passwordRule]"
          ></v-text-field>
```

as it currently shows "Min. 8 characters with at least one capital letter, a number and a special character." as error message,

How can I achieve like if password doesn't have capital letter it should display only message like "Atleast 1 capital letter". and if password doesn't have a number it should display "a number is required"

Please guide me how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current rule assumes that the password must contain only **latin uppercase** letters.

If it's OK, use `uppercaseEn` rule from code below. Otherwise it should be better to use `uppercase` rule.

```js
<v-text-field
  v-model="password"
  :rules="[rules.uppercaseEn, rules.special, rules.number, rules.length]"
  label="Password"
></v-text-field>
...
data () {
  return {
    password: '',
    rules: {
      uppercase: value => {
        //For non-latin letters also
        return (value && value.toLowerCase() !== value) || 'At least 1 uppercase letter'
      },
      uppercaseEn: value => {
        //For latin letters only
        return /[A-Z]/.test(value) || 'At least 1 uppercase letter (A-Z only)'
      },
      number: value => {
        return /\d/.test(value) || 'At least 1 number'
      },
      special: value => {
        return /[!@#\$%\^&\*]/.test(value) || 'At least 1 special symbol'
      },
      length: value => {
        return (value && value.length >= 8) || 'Min password length: 8 symbols'
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/vYdBmVd).